# can you pass a serialized c# class to json via jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, serialization

let's say i have a class:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class MyFoo
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to pass data from my Webservice to the JQuery ajax this class to the JS and parse it like an object.

```
[WebMethod]
public MyFoo GetData()
{
   return (new MyFoo);
}

$.ajax({
success: function(val) {
    var MyFoo = val;
    $('#textbox1').val(MyFoo.ID);
    $('#textbox2').val(MyFoo.Name);
}
});
```

Comment: check this pass a serialized c# class to json via jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what framework you're using but there are lots of ways to achieve this. For example, in MVC you can return a `JsonResult` that contains any object, and it will be serialised to JSON in a straightforward way.

Given the `[WebMethod]` attribute I guess you're using Microsoft's Web Services framework and I think it will accept and return JSON if that's what you request in your `ajax` call.

[Here's a blog post on this subject.](http://geekswithblogs.net/JuanDoNeblo/archive/2007/10/24/json_in_aspnetajax_part2.aspx)

Comment: hi Daniel, i'm using asp.net forms. would that matter?

Comment: I think it's the same stuff. Just googling for [WebMethod] json I find tons of examples of people doing this and explaining how.